# PHP Redirecting users on login based on MySQL record

Tags: php, mysql, session, redirect, authentication

My page does not redirect correctly. It only takes me to '**staffmenu.php**' even if all records are 1.

The database holds login data like this:

```
| staff_ID | username | Password | Page1 | Page2 | Page3 |
----------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |  admin   |  abc123  |   1   |   1   |   1   |
|    2     |  emp01   |  pass45  |   0   |   0   |   1   |
|    3     |  emp02   |  pword7  |   1   |   0   |   0   |
```

Now, what I want to do is only redirect users that have a "1" for access for all three pages (in this case username: 'admin' ) to '**adminmenu.php**', the rest should go to a different page called '**staffmenu.php**'

```html
<?php
include("includes/con_db.php");



// Define $username and $password 
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password']; 



$sql="SELECT username, password, page1, page2, page3 FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $row[3] = $f;
  $row[4] = $s;
  $row[5] = $r;



// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

// If result no matched $username and $password, invalid log in
if ($count=='0')
  {
    header("Location:index.php?status=login");
  } 
else 
   {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
 
  if ($f =='1' && $s =='1' && $r =='1')
    {
    $_SESSION["AdminLoggedIn"] = true;
    header("Location:adminmenu.php");
    }
  else 
    {
      $_SESSION["StaffLoggedIn"] = true;
      header("location:staffmenu.php");
    }
   }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `$f`, `$s` and `$r` are not defined (for what we see of your code) and what is $row?

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you enter as username `''; DELETE FROM users`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. In this short example you have a number of dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) coming from a complete lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Comment: @Mikey nothing would happen. MySQL won't execute multiple queries at once.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to have several problem in your code.

1/ You execute your query but doesn't get the results. So you should have

```
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

2/ For what we see of code, this three lines are useless:

```
$row[3] = $f;
$row[4] = $s;
$row[5] = $r;
```

since `$row` is not used, and `$f`, `$s` and `$r` doesn't exists. But maybe there is some hidden code...

3/ You should assign the variables for your checks

```
$f = $user['page1'];
$s = $user['page2'];
$r = $user['page3'];
```

So you should have something like that

```
$sql= "SELECT username, password, page1, page2, page3 FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

// If result no matched $username and $password, invalid log in
if ($count=='0')
{
    header("Location:index.php?status=login");
} 
else 
{
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $f = $user['page1'];
    $s = $user['page2'];
    $r = $user['page3'];

    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

    if ($f =='1' && $s =='1' && $r =='1')
    {
       $_SESSION["AdminLoggedIn"] = true;
       header("Location:adminmenu.php");
    }
    else 
   {
      $_SESSION["StaffLoggedIn"] = true;
      header("location:staffmenu.php");
   }
}

mysql_close($con);
```

Also, do not save password without encryption and check your query for SQL injection and use prepared queries.

some ressources, but you can find a lot of documentation on internet about mysql injection and how to protect you from it.

http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: It's always good to link to the documentation but I think you put the French link in by accident.